# Stuck on white screen when using email ending on googlemail.com instead of gmail.com

Tags: google-oauth

Since couple of months ago we get a lot of reports in our app from users who are stuck on white screen when trying to log in with google social oath, it only happens for users who still use old googlemail.com accounts and it happens right after you select an account and right before Allow Permission screen should appear.

Here are more reports of similar issue: https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/4692671?hl=en

Here's a video if a bug:
https://youtu.be/aaDKKzbA72s

We have over 100 of affected users, 100% of them have @googlemail.com, asking user to switch to gmail.com does help.

I am using this plugin for Google OAuth, just a reminder that it works fine for all accounts ending with gmail.com, and it used to work for googlemail.com also.

I have a suspicion that it's something to do with scopes and a consent screen. I request following scopes:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

it is getting stuck on infinite preloader just before consent screen suppose to show and only for accounts with googlemail.com

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .requestProfile()
        .build();
```

Comment: Update about this issue: this issue is only happening if you show a consent screen, I was requesting OpenID scope so we had consent screen shown, if you only request email and password scopes then you won't have a consent screen

Comment: `email` and `profile` scopes *

Answer (score 0):

Can we have a look at your code? To better understand what the problem is. As you can see, this is a problem in the application code, or in poor integration. Perhaps a problem with the API

Comment: I actually think this is a problem in API as more people report this problem since April this year. I am struggling to find a way to report this directly to Google, that's why I posted it here. Will share a code in a bit

Comment: Also how my code can be wrong if it works for all users except for users with googlemail.com accounts